# Explain what the teacher did, convergence of improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, proof-explanation

I'd like someone to explain what the teacher did, because I'm not sure I understand.

Basically, the question is for which values of $p$, does the integral $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{t \log ^p(1+t)}$$ converge.

Here is what the teacher did:

He said that this integral converges, if and only if the integral $$\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t \log ^p(t)}$$

converges.

and this integral converges when $p=2$, since we can use the transform $e^x=t$:

$$\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t \log ^p(t)}=\int_{\log 2}^{\infty}\frac{e^xdx}{e^x \log ^p(e^x)}=\int_{\log 2}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^p}$$ which converges for $p \geq 2$.

I agree and understand why the second integral converges when $p \geq 2$, but I don't understand why the first integral converges if and only if the second one converges. i dont see the relation between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, one makes the substitution $u = t+1$ (and then renames $u$ again to $t$), to write the integral as

$$\int_2^\infty \frac{dt}{(t-1)\log^p t}.$$

Then one sandwiches the integrand

$$\frac{1}{t\log^p t} < \frac{1}{(t-1)\log^p t} \leqslant \frac{2}{t\log^p t}$$

to obtain the equivalence that one integral converges if and only if the other does (which is the case if and only if $p > 1$).